# How to convert Object into array in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to convert an object with specific properties into array of string containing properties values. For an instance take Object `Employee` with below properties with values

```
Employee.Name='XYZ'
Employee.ID=123
Employee.Address='ABC'
```

I want this all to be in array as

```
var arr=['XYZ',123,'ABC']
```

How to iterate over the properties. Is this possible? Please assist here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

```
var arr = $.map(Employee, function(value, key){
    return value
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DF3Qc/)

**Note: The order of loop is not dependable, so the order of values in the array may not be always same**

---

Another way to handle it is to use a fixed array of keys so that the output array will have a predefined sequence

```
var keys = ['Name', 'ID', 'Address'];
var Employee = {};
Employee.Name = 'XYZ'
Employee.ID = 123
Employee.Address = 'ABC'
var arr = $.map(keys, function (key, idx) {
    return Employee[key]
})
console.log(arr)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/s2KGe/)

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the object like this

```
var arr = [];
for (var key in Employee) {
    arr.push(Employee[key]);
}
```

**Note:** Order is not defined in this case

Comment: +1 but it's best to use `var arr = [];` rather than `var arr = new Array();`. Also worth noting that the order is not defined.

Comment: Ah i'll update, btw why is arr=[] better the arr=new Array() Is it faster?

Comment: @ Anton: *"Is it faster?"* [Usually](http://jsperf.com/creation-array), but that's not important. `Array` can be redefined (`var Array`, for instance), and it's confusing and inconsistent: `var a = new Array(5);` gives you an array containing no entries with a `length` of `5`. `var a = new Array("5");` gives you an array with one entry (`"5"`). `var a = new Array(5, 2);` gives you an array with two entries (`5` and `2`) and a `length` of `2`. In contrast, `var a = [5];` gives you an array with one entry and `var a = [5, 2];` an array with two entries. Consistent and clear.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah i see now why it could be confusing. Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each property and add it's value to the array:

```
var arr = [];

for (var prop in Employee) {
    if (Employee.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        arr.push(Employee[prop]);
    }
}
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/2PHpZ/

Or using jQuery:

```
var arr = $.map(Employee, function(propValue) {
    return propValue;
});
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/2PHpZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray=[];

for (var key in Employee) {
  if (Employee.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    myArray.push(Employee[key]));
  }
}
```

Comment: what is `p` in your `if`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var Employee = {};
Employee.Name='XYZ';
Employee.ID=123;
Employee.Address='ABC';

var empArray =[];

$.each(Employee,function(item){
    empArray.push(item);
});

console.log(empArray);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sesubash/cZjd8/)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript since 1.7. Reference to [JavaScript language advanced Tips & Tricks](http://code.google.com/p/jslibs/wiki/JavascriptTips).

```
var arr = [Employee.Name,Employee.ID,Employee.Address];
```